# cos(4v) + cos(v) = 0

Tags: trigonometry

I am given the following equation:

$$\cos 4v + \cos v = 0$$

My attempt:

$$\cos4v = -\cos v$$

$$\cos4v = \cos(\pi \pm v)$$

$$4v = \pm \pi \pm v + 2\pi n$$

---

$$4v_1 = \pi + v_1 + 2\pi n$$

$$4v_2 = -\pi - v_2 + 2\pi n$$

$$4v_3 = +\pi - v_3 + 2\pi n$$

$$4v_4 = -\pi + v_4 + 2\pi n$$

---

$$v_1 = \frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{2\pi n}{3}$$

$$v_2 = -\frac{\pi}{5} + \frac{2\pi n}{5}$$

$$v_3 = \frac{\pi}{5} + \frac{2\pi n}{5}$$

$$v_4 = -\frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{2\pi n}{3}$$

However, the answer is simply the positive solutions i.e:

$$v_1 = \frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{2\pi n}{3}$$

$$v_3 = \frac{\pi}{5} + \frac{2\pi n}{5}$$

Why? What am I missing?

Comment: It's a bit strange to write $\pm\pi\pm v\pm2\pi n$ instead of $\pm v\pm2\pi n$, which is the same thing expressed more simply. Adding $\pm\pi$ at the beginning adds a complication that serves no purpose. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry but $\pm\pi\pm2\pi\mathbb Z\ne\pm2\pi\mathbb Z$, the former is $\pi+2\pi\mathbb Z$ while the latter is $2\pi\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n$ is not necessarily positive.
$$ -\dfrac{\pi}{3} = \dfrac{\pi}{3} + \dfrac{2\pi(-1)}{3}$$
etc.

Comment: Aah, I should have seen that. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers are actually the same as the official answers. If you draw a cast diagram you can see this

Comment: What is a "cast diagram"? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think he means something like [this](http://thomaswhitham.pbworks.com/f/The+CAST+diagram.pdf), which indicates which of the three primary trigonometric function is/are positive in a given quadrant, CAST standing for Cosine, All, Sine, Tangent. That doesn't make it much clearer, though.

Comment: @HDE 226868. It's a quadrant diagram, i.e. a unit circle centred at the origin on the axes showing the solutions. I don't have a suitable drawing package on my iPad, otherwise I would draw it for you...

Comment: oh .... It's one of those mnemonics used to help people fake learning math.  I suppose these can also have honest uses, but that's how I've always thought of those. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy. I'm puzzled by the phrase "fake learning math". What does it mean?

Comment: @DavidQuinn : It means lots of students get through secondary-school mathematics and first-year calculus by memorizing things, including algorithms for finding derivatives, integrals, limits, etc., without attempting to understand anything; they want and accept dogma.  In honest learning of mathematics, on the one hand one believes things that textbooks and professors say (within reason) but on the other hand one is always working toward understanding independently of those authorities why things work the way they do. But numerous students show up in math courses thinking$\ldots$

Comment: $\ldots$of learning things in those courses ONLY as the price of a grade, rather than what they show up for.  If they can fake it and get a grade, that's fine with them.  The system encourages this behavior, in part because they bring in tuition money (and that is prostitution) and in part because professors want to work on their research and are contemptuous of those lower-level courses, and in part because of demagogic rhetoric about how "our country" is served by forcing people whose talents are well spent on other things than$\ldots$

Comment: $\ldots$mathematics to take math courses.  The result is that most college graduates think they know what mathematics is and believe many falsehoods about it (how does that serve any country's interests?) including that learning mathematics consists of learning algorithms. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: It's like FOIL (first,outer,inner,last) to remember that (a+b)(c+d)=ab+ad+bc+bd without having any idea why.

Comment: For the original Q, you need $\cos 4x  = 2 (\cos 2x)^2-1$ and  $ \cos 2x=2(\cos x)^2-1$ so it reduces to a polynomial equation of degree 4 in  $\cos x$.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have posted this observation on this thread. Do you mean this as a comment to the OP, or perhaps an answer

Comment: @MichaelHardy. I find your comments very interesting and worthy of a longer response, although this may not be the best place. Your points probably apply as much to the UK as to the US school and college system. By way of mitigation, all I can say is that the cast diagram is a fairly innocuous device used for introducing the definitions of $sin$ $cos$ and $tan$ of the general angle, and can also be used as a quick check to see if one set of trig solutions expressed in a certain way is equivalent to the same set expressed in a different way.

Comment: @user254665. I don't think anyone actually memorizes FOIL as an algebraic formula, but rather as a *pattern* to follow when distributing brackets. It is also referred to as "fireworks" because of the lines, corresponding to the four multiplications, which students are encouraged to draw when they are first learning it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials),
$$ T_4(x)+T_1(x) = 8x^4-8x^2+x+1 = (x+1)(8x^2(x-1)+1) = (1+x)(1-2x)(1+2x-4x^2) $$
hence the solutions are given by $\cos(v)\in\left\{-1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4},\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}\right\}$ or:
$$ v\in \left\{\pm\frac{\pi}{5},\pm\frac{\pi}{3},\pm\frac{3\pi}{5},\pm\pi\right\}+2\pi\mathbb{Z}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cosine identity to simplify:
$$\cos(u)+\cos(w)=2\cos\left(\frac{u+w}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{u-w}{2}\right)$$
You then take $u=4v$ and $w=v$:
$$\cos(4v)+\cos(v)=2\cos\left(\frac{4v+v}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{4v-v}{2}\right)=0$$
You should then be able to simplify and solve.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that $$\cos(x)-\cos(y)=-2\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)$$
sorry i misreaded the post use that
$$\cos(x)+\cos(y)=2 \cos \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}\right)$$